# Systemd jupyter service only works after service restart

Tags: ubuntu, lan, systemd, jupyter-notebook

Using systemd, I am trying to setup my **Ubuntu 20.04** workstation to host a **Jupyter lab** environment for my LAN.

This somewhat works. If I manually issue the command to start Jupyter on port 8888, `jupyter lab --ip pcc.local`, this works fine.

To automate this I created a systemd service:

**/etc/systemd/system/jupyter.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Jupyter Lab service on port 8888
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=idle
#Restart=always
#RestartSec=1
User=wsuser
ExecStart= /home/wsuser/local/bin/jupyter lab --ip pcc.local
WorkingDirectory=/home/wsuser/


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I issue the command `sudo systemctl start jupyter`, I can access the jupyter notebook over LAN by navigating to https://pcc.local:8888 in a browser.

After testing this, I enabled the service (`sudo systemctl enable jupyter`) and rebooted.

I checked the status of the service and got that is was running w/o errors:

```
 jupyter.service - Jupyter Lab service on port 8888
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/jupyter.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-06-21 21:17:01 CEST; 4min 22s ago
   Main PID: 1019 (jupyter-lab)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 19035)
     Memory: 74.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/jupyter.service
             └─1019 /usr/bin/python3 /home/wsuser/.local/bin/jupyter-lab --ip pcc.local

jun 21 21:17:01 PCC systemd[1]: Started Jupyter Lab service on port 8888.
jun 21 21:17:06 PCC jupyter[1019]: [W 21:17:06.871 LabApp] JupyterLab server extension not enabled, manually loading...
jun 21 21:17:06 PCC jupyter[1019]: [I 21:17:06.876 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/wsuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab
jun 21 21:17:06 PCC jupyter[1019]: [I 21:17:06.876 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/wsuser/.local/share/jupyter/lab
jun 21 21:17:06 PCC jupyter[1019]: [I 21:17:06.877 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/wsuser
jun 21 21:17:06 PCC jupyter[1019]: [I 21:17:06.877 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
jun 21 21:17:06 PCC jupyter[1019]: [I 21:17:06.877 LabApp] https://pcc.local:8888/
jun 21 21:17:06 PCC jupyter[1019]: [I 21:17:06.877 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

This *looks* fine, however, if i navigate to https://pcc.local:8888/ on my other machine, I cannot connect (Firefox says 'Unable to connect Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at pcc.local:8888.')

As soon as I restart the service, `sudo systemctl restart jupyter`, the jupyter notebook is available over LAN.

I tried setting the service type from simple to idle, to make sure it is one of the last services that starts.

**Why do I need to restart the service after boot, and what can I do to fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by changing
`After=network.target`
to
`After=syslog.target network.target`